# Swift MapKit Polygon overlay

Tags: swift, dictionary, mapkit, overlay, polygon

I have a polygon on my MapView, now i want to add a 2 one but in a different color.
Is there a way todo so?

This is the MapView where should be a 2. Polygon overlay in different color 
[image]

```
   func addBoundry()
    {
        var points=[
                    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.711963, 8.738251),
                    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.711963, 8.763717),
                    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.718574, 8.763717),
                    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.71855, 8.754448)]

        let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: &points, count: points.count)

        mapView.addOverlay(polygon)
    }

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
    if overlay is MKPolygon {
        let polygonView = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        polygonView.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.847, blue: 1, alpha: 0.25)

        return polygonView
    }

    return nil
}
```

Is there a way todo so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved via .title to use it in a if